# Installing Bitwig Studio .deb "but it is not installable"

Tags: software-installation, release-odin

I'm trying to install Bitwig Studio 4.1 which comes as a .deb package. I'm using Eddy, and it's giving me this error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  bitwig-studio: Depends: zlib1g:i386 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libx11-xcb1:i386 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libxau6:i386 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libxdmcp6:i386 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libxrender1:i386 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libfontconfig1:i386 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libxcb-icccm4:i386 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libxcb-util1:i386 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libxcb-shm0:i386 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libxcb-xinput0:i386 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libxkbcommon0:i386 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libxkbcommon-x11-0:i386 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libpixman-1-0:i386 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libcairo2:i386 but it is not installable
```

How can I install Bitwig? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that BitWig Studio is looking for very old 32bit packages which are no longer available in the default Ubuntu repositories. Doing a quick search it looks like several of these packages are available in 64bit so its not that they're completely unsupported.

I would look to see if Bitwig has any support for what to do about 32bit packages not being available.

Comment: I got a response from Bitwig, turns out they have a [Flatpak version](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.bitwig.BitwigStudio) which they're just not advertising on their website!

Everything worked as expected using that. :)